# Obx widget is not updating on observable variable change

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have two forms which updates a non-observable User model on the form input's `onChanged`. Along with this, I have a state enum (observable) which determines whether or not the user is registering/logging in.

The login controller roughly has this implementation

```dart
class LoginController extends GetxController {
    Rx<LoginState> loginState = LoginState.notLoggedIn.obs;
    UserModel userModel = UserModel();

    bool get isLoggingIn => loginState.value == LoginState.loggingIn;
    bool get shouldDisableLoginFormSubmit =>
      isLoggingIn || !userModel.email.isEmail || userModel.password.isEmpty;

    ...

}
```

In the login form, I have a button with an `isDisabled` property as one of the children of a `Column` widget

Rough implementation of the form

```dart
class LoginForm extends StatelessWidget {
    LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    LoginController loginController = Get.find<LoginController>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            ...
            Obx(() => InputTextFormField(
                onChanged: _onEmailFormInputChanged,
                inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                isDisabled: loginController.isLoggingIn)),
            ...
            Obx(() => GenericRoundedGradientButton(
                isDisabled: loginController.shouldDisableLoginFormSubmit,
                onPressed: loginController.signInWithEmail)),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The `LoginWithEmailButton` is rebuilding on each form input change, which is what I want.

A similar approach to the registration form however, shows that the `RegisterWithEmailButton` is not rebuilding on the form input's `onChanged`.

Registration controller:

```dart
class RegisterController extends GetxController {
    Rx<RegisterState> registerState = RegisterState.notRegistered.obs;
    UserModel userModel = UserModel();
    bool get isRegistering => registerState.value == RegisterState.registering;
    bool get shouldDisableRegisterFormSubmit =>
        isRegistering ||
        userModel.fullName.isEmpty ||
        !userModel.email.isEmail ||
        userModel.password.isEmpty;

    ...

}
```

And the registration form:

```dart
class RegisterForm extends StatelessWidget {
    RegisterForm({
        Key? key,
    }) : super(key: key);

    RegisterController registerController = Get.find<RegisterController>();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        Obx(() => InputTextFormField(
            onChanged: _onEmailFormInputChanged,
            inputType: TextInputType.email,
            isDisabled: registerController.isRegistering)),
        ...
        Obx(() => GenericRoundedGradientButton(
            isDisabled: registerController.shouldDisableRegisterFormSubmit,
            onPressed: registerController.registerWithEmail))
        ]);
    }
}
```

However, the register with email button does not update its state. Both controllers are initialised in a previous page and kept as permanent. Has anyone faced this sort of issue before?

Comment: What is the implementation of `registerWithEmail` ? What function is executed when you press this button?

Comment: @Kozubi it calls a method that returns a `Future<void>`. I don't think that has anything to do with the problem as the method is never called while filling up the form. Rather, the problem right now is that the state is not updating on the input form field's `onChanged` for one form but it is for the other and both forms and controllers are incredibly similar (different strings, extra form fields, etc.)

Comment: Can you show the `_onEmailFormInputChanged` method?